# What is the technology behind screen sharing?

Tags: game-design

Came across an app called `Draw N Guess`([iTunes link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/draw-n-guess-multiplayer-online/id532137502?mt=8)) and the app uses screen sharing, i.e what a player draws is visible to others. I'm wondering how they are doing it in real time. I believe it is a cross-platform app. I got curios to know what is the technology behind it! It must be very interesting to learn :)

P.S. If this is not the site to ask plain question (i.e unrelated to programming), can you let me know where I can ask such questions? TIY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image appears all in one go...

1. User A draws it
2. User A presses a button
3. A snapshot is taken of the drawing, into an image
4. The image is sent to user B

If you watch the other user draw it

1. User A makes some kind of input gesture (draw with finger)
2. User A's app converts that to a draw command and executes it locally
3. The command is sent to user B
4. User B's app executes the command

It's not screen sharing. Screen sharing shares an area of the screen regardless of which app is running.

Comment: So, it must use web APIs to communicate each drawing stroke. Thanks for the answer (y)